# ¿Cómo quito la columna FK de la consulta y dejando solo el nombre?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Veréis, tengo una consulta construida para mostrar en una tabla html, todos los datos contenidos en una tabla de la base de datos. También hecha para mostrar el nombre en lugar de la FK:

```
SELECT tbl_libro.*,tbl_categoria.nombre_categoria FROM tbl_libro INNER JOIN tbl_categoria
         ON tbl_libro.id_categoria=tbl_categoria.id_categoria
```

Y aquí el esquema de las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al ejecutar la consulta obtengo las columnas siguientes:

| Id_libro | Nombre_libro | Precio_libro | id_categoria | Nombre_categoria |

La `id_categoria` mostrada es la FK de la `tbl_libro`, que es una columna que no quiero mostrar. Sé que podría indicar que columnas mostrar indicándolo explícitamente en el select en lugar de poner el asterisco. Pero la consulta la quiero usar de forma dinámica, de tal forma que escoja la tabla que escoja, siempre me mostrará todas las columnas a excepción del FK. Pero si se os ocurre alguna otra forma de hacer esto último comentadlo sin problema.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. Pon en el `SELECT` las columnas cuyos datos quieres que aparezcan. ¿Eso no resuelve tu problema? Si no lo resuelve, ¿por qué no lo resuelve?

Comment: Creo que la única manera en que no aparezca la columna id_categoria , es poniendo únicamente las columnas que quieres mostrar, evitando el asterisco.

Comment: @A. Cedano no lo resuelve porque esa query la quiero usar con cualquier tabla. Por eso no quiero indicar explícitamente el nombre de las columnas, ya que las otras tablas son distintas. Estaba pensando que quizá se podría con algún where, pero no sé cómo exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

Mientras leía vuestros comentarios y respuestas, se me ocurrió una idea para solucionar el problema. A ver qué os parece.

Ya que comentáis que tengo que indicar si o si las columnas en el `SELECT`, lo he hecho de la siguiente forma. Hago una consulta al `information_schema.COLUMNS` para extraer el nombre de las columnas a excepción de la columna FK. Después, paso el array a string con el delimitador `',tbl_libro.'` , para obtener la variable `$nomcol` De tal forma que si la incluyo dentro de la query se genera una cadena automática en el `SELECT`.

Para acabar con crear una variable que contenga el nombre de la tabla que se está consultando, ya estaría todo de manera dinámica.

```
$sql="SELECT column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_libro' and table_schema = 'bd_libreria' and `COLUMN_KEY` != 'MUL'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
while(($columnas = mysqli_fetch_array($result))){

  $columna[]=$columnas[0];


  }

$nomcol = implode(',tbl_libro.', $columna);

$query="SELECT $nomcol,tbl_categoria.nombre_categoria FROM tbl_libro INNER JOIN tbl_categoria
         ON tbl_libro.id_categoria=tbl_categoria.id_categoria";
```

Comment: Podrias traerte todas las columnas de tu tabla con el `GROUP_CONCAT` y concatenarle el ',tbl_juego.', algo así `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('tbl_juego.',COLUMN_NAME))`, así solo te traerias un solo dato ya concatenado, no se si entendí bien lo que intentas hacer <.<